# How to get the array size in a function without any additional arguments

Tags: c

```
main()
{
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   function(arr);
}
int function(int a[])
{       

}
```

Here I want to get the length of the array which was not initialized. The main function in my case is which I do not have any idea..assume I am getting the array elements from some other program.

Comment: pass extra argument, or use strcut, or append one more information to array = length of array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 6):

Arrays decay to pointers when used as arguments to a function:

```
int function(int a[]);
```

and

```
int function(int *a);
```

are the same.

This means that you cannot know how many elements are in an array that is passed to your function unless you have a separate parameter that indicates the length of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out how many elements there are in `arr` in `main()` by `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`.

However, you cannot use this method in that `function()`. Because in this case `a` is a pointer to `int`, you need to pass the length of `a` as an extra argument to `function()`, like this:

```
int function(int a[], int len) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The function just receives a pointer (an address to a location in memory).

You have two options: pass the lenght of the array as an extra argument to the function (as other suggested)...

...or establish a convention (if possibile) where a certain value on the array represent the last element (so you can get the length by counting elements until the end-of-array item).

That's what happens with C strings. A C string is an array of `char`s where a character with value of `0` indicates the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int ArraySize (int *); 

main ()


{

   int array[] = {1,2,3}; 
   printf("The size of the array is%d \n", ArraySize(array)); 

}

int ArraySize (int *a)

{    

   for (int i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++);
   return i;
}
```

Comment: -1: in your `ArraySize` function the for control variable `i` ceases to exist at the end of the loop, before the `return` statement; and `return`, if this worked, would attempt to return an nonexistent variable. Also, the loop tries to access elements of the array that do not exist.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, i will be incremented until the value a[i] equals Null (end of array). Name of array is passed to the function.

Comment: You are wrong, arrays are not automatically terminated by a null value. The function `ArraySize()` will go reading over the end of the array, return a wrong result (when will encounter a 0) and possibly read in a memory area the program have no access to resulting in a crash.

Comment: Do I need to terminate the array with null? e.g. int array[] ={1,2,3,NULL}. I'm new to C and trying to learn the ropes :)

Comment: @Abeer: You can't have values of different types in an array. `1`, `2`, `-42`, `1000` and so on are values of type `int`; `NULL` is a pointer value. You cannot mix pointers and integers. *You could signal the end of the array with a `0`, but then you couldn't have a real `0` as an element: `int array[] = {-2, -1, 0, 1};`*